# PhantomJS not playing nice with RequireJS+Jasmine

Tags: javascript, requirejs, jasmine, phantomjs

I have some tests running with RequireJS and Jasmine. I have a Jasmine test harness file that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        require(["fakeTest"], function () {
                window.onload();
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My fakeTest file is very simple:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    describe("fake test", function () {
        it("test nothing", function () {
            expect(1).toEqual(1);
        });
    });
});
```

If I run this in FireFox/Chrome then everything works fine; I see one test and that it passed. If I run this with PhantomJS though, I start getting problems. Running it with the remote debugger flag I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'fakeTest'
>
> phantomjs://bootstrap.js:299 in require
>   phantomjs://bootstrap.js:263 in require

If I try changing my harness file so that it says requirejs[("fakeTest"...... instead of just require, I get this error:

> Error: Script error for "fakeTest"
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:140
>   in defaultOnError
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:544
>   in onError
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1732
>   in onScriptError   :0 in appendChild
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1952
>   in load
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1679
>   in load
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:829
>   in load
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:819
>   in fetch
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:851
>   in check
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1177
>   in enable
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1550
>   in enable
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1162
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:131
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:56
>   in each
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1114
>   in enable
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:783
>   in init
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js:1453

If I put in a completely invalid module name, I get the same errors in both cases.

I'm totally lost as to why this is happening. I've played around with changing the path for fakeTest in the harness file but nothing changes. I've simplified the harness file as much as I could, but since I'm still seeing this i'm not sure what else to try. Anyone have any ideas?

*edit*

I've removed everything to do with Jasmine and just have fakeTest do an alert. Now I get errors saying

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.20/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["fakeTest"], function () {});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    alert('foo');
});
```

> "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: requirejs"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of write `html` use [karma with requirejs plugin](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/requirejs.html).

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],

    files: [
      {pattern: 'Scripts/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'test/*.js', included: false},

      'test/test-main.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    browsers: ['PhantomJS']
  });
};
```

**test/test-main.js**

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
var allTestFiles = [];

// Get a list of all the test files to include
Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
  if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
    // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
    // If you require sub-dependencies of test files to be loaded as-is (requiring file extension)
    // then do not normalize the paths
    var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
    allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
  }
});

require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base',

  // example of using a couple path translations (paths), to allow us to refer to different library dependencies, without using relative paths
  paths: {
    // Put Your requirejs config here
  },

  // example of using a shim, to load non AMD libraries (such as underscore)
  shim: {
  },

  // dynamically load all test files
  deps: allTestFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

This is example files. Fix it and run

```
karma run
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use Karma for this, for other reasons not worth discussing here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js" 
        data-main="Tests/main"></script>
```

Move test files to **Tests** directory.

In **Tests/main.js** use Your requirejs config and run main tests file.

```
var deps = ['Tests/fakeTest'];

require.config({
  baseUrl: '..',

  paths: {
      'jasmine': ['Scripts/jasmine//jasmine'],
      'jasmine-html': ['Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html'],
      'jasmine-boot': ['Scripts/jasmine/boot']
  },
  // shim: makes external libraries compatible with requirejs (AMD)
  shim: {
    'jasmine-html': {
      deps : ['jasmine']
    },
    'jasmine-boot': {
      deps : ['jasmine', 'jasmine-html']
    }
  }
});

require(['jasmine-boot'], function () {
  require(deps, function(){
    //trigger Jasmine
    window.onload();
  })
});
```

In **index.html** run only **Tests/main.js** file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js" data-main="Tests/main"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the error in the original post. When I launch phantomJS from cmd, I just get the second error from my post.

Comment: Where is Your `fakeTest.js`? In root (baseUrl)?

Comment: Yes. I've copied it to Tests/ as well.

Comment: I've made some changes in `Tests/main.js`.

Comment: Had to set baseUrl to ./, and add a callback to call window.onload(). Once I got it working I still get the same error: "script error for 'main'"

Comment: Now it's working example. If You want, I put it on GitGub

Comment: Thanks, but i've edited OP to simplify this greatly. Turns out this has nothing to do with Jasmine; I see the errors with just RequireJS and a JS file.

Comment: Edit my example and comment jasmine-related code. Works.